# HTML CSS, how to create a Side bar or column

Tags: html, css

i'm a bit of newbie to HTML and CSS, i'm currently working on a project from a given screenshot, and i hit a block. i'm not sure how i can divide the text to look the same as the model. when doing a side bar, it gives me a complete separate div. 
project link: http://postimg.org/image/no7gsn23z/
my so progress :( 
thanks for the replies, you guys All Rock! 
but i still have the same problem, could you point me to where i need to make the change? 
bellow are the screenshots:

so i tried your suggestions, but it kinda gave me the same issue: it added the side bar on a separate space, i'd like to have one content separate to two columns: bellow are the images for how it looks now for both issues the banner placement and the side bar:

sidebar
http://postimg.org/image/4ts1bylfd/

my other issue is placing the last banner right bellow the main menu, but it always keep a white space: 
bellow is my coding so far:

```
<html>

<head>

<title> Welcome to Groundswell </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mstyle.css" />
    <style>
        .position {position:absolute;right:200px; width:auto;top:80px;}
        .bannerpos {position: absolute;height:auto;width:auto;}
        body {background-image:url("page_background.jpg");padding: 70px;}
        div {background-color: white;}
        .ulmenu { list-style-type: none; display: inline;float: right}
        .limenu{float:left;margin:20px;display: inline;}
       .column{column-count: auto;
  column-gap:40px;
 column-rule:4px outset #ff00ff;
 }
 }
 }
        h2{color: brown;}
        h4,h1{color:gray;}
    </style>
 </head>

 <body>
<div id="outerDiv">

<div style="background-image: url(banner.jpg);" id="header">

<img src="banner.jpg" alt="Groundwell Logo" width=100% height=auto />

<div id="contactButton">

<img class="position" src="contact-off.png" alt="contact us"/>
</div>

 <div style="position: relative;bottom:70px;" id="mainMenu" >
       <ul class=ulmenu>
        <li class=limenu><a href=""> <img src="home-off.png"> </a></li>
        <li class=limenu><a href=""> <img src="gear-off.png"> </a></li>
        <li class=limenu><a href=""> <img src="lifestyle-off.png"> </a></li>
        <li class=limenu><a href=""> <img src="videos-off.png"> </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div> <!-- mainMenu -->

</div> <!-- header --> 

<div style=background-image: url(home_banner.jpg) ; >
              <img src="home_banner.jpg" alt="home banner" width=100% height=auto; />

</div>

<div id="content">

    <div id="mainContent">
<br>
 <br>
    <br>
        <br>
    <h1>Welcome to Groundswell</h1>
    <p>

  lifestyle, or watching some of the sickest video this side of the pipeline, we've    got you covered. On our site you'll find:
    </p>
    <ul>
<li>The latest gear</li>
<li>Surfing journals</li>
<li>Surfing photos</li>
<li>Competition videos</li>
<li>Surf condition reports</li>
<li>...and much more!</li>
    </ul>

    <p>So take off your sandals and wax your board up... you're here.</p>
    <h2>Latest News</h2>
<h4>.</h4>
    <p></p>

    <h4>Velosurty releases new board</h4>
    <p>!</p>

    <h4>Like the new look?</h4>
    <p>You may have noticed things look a little different here at Groundswell! We'll we decided it was time for a change and wanted a fresher look. </p>
    </div><!-- mainContent -->

   <span class=column>
        <h4>This month's surfer's journal</h4>
        <p>Josh Cambria pens this month's surfer journal. Check out his month-long   surfing experience as he surfs up the coast from San Diego up to Ventura. Along the way he meets several celebrities and finds a new favorite board.
    Check it out</p>
  </span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is code is in regards to the link: http://postimg.org/image/no7gsn23z/

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <style type="text/css">
        body {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }

    .navBar {
        margin-left: 25px;
        margin-right: 25px;
        background-color: #74BAE9;
        padding-bottom: 25px;
    }

        .navBar ul {
            list-style: none;
        }

        .navBar ul li {
            float: left;
        }

        .navBar ul li a {
            color: #000;
            margin-right: 15px;
        }

    .containter {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

    .leftContent {
        margin-left: 15px;
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }

    .rightBar {
        margin-top: 10%;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 25%;
    }
        </style>
        <div  class="navBar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
            <div class="containter">

            <div class="leftContent">
                <h1>Header</h1>
                <p>This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. </p>
                <ul>
                    <li>List Item</li>
                    <li>List Item</li>
                    <li>List Item</li>
                    <li>List Item</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="rightBar">
                <img src="#">
                <br>
                <h3>Some Header</h3>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys
i finished it, it still looks like a rookies' job, but kinda ok :D
here's the link: 
http://www.javascriptworkshop.com/CIS114/student7/midterm/midterm.html

Comment: It looks good! Sorry my examples were bland. I was just trying to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.navBar {
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    background-color: #74BAE9;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

    .navBar ul {
        list-style: none;
    }

    .navBar ul li {
        float: left;
    }

    .navBar ul li a {
        color: #000;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }

.containter {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.leftContent {
    margin-left: 15px;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.rightBar {
    margin-top: 10%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 25%;
}
    </style>
    <div  class="navBar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
        <div class="containter">

        <div class="leftContent">
            <h1>Header</h1>
            <p>This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. </p>
            <ul>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="rightBar">
            <img src="#">
            <br>
            <h3>Some Header</h3>
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe judging between two different directions is rather simple, but sure, if it makes your day.

Comment: Lol I just didn't get your logic pushing something to the left and stating it's on the right! "it's a feature" :)

Comment: so i tried your suggestions, but it kinda gave me the same issue: it added the side bar on a separate space, i'd like to have one content separate to two columns: bellow are the images for how it looks now for both issues the banner placement and the side bar:

http://postimg.org/image/4ts1bylfd/
Banner issue: 
http://postimg.org/image/og07jhzwl/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are looking for (please be more specific), but maybe this layout will help you out:

### HTML

```
<body>
  <header></header>
  <nav></nav>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

### CSS

```
nav{
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1;
    border-top:250px solid lightyellow;
    width: 250px;
    right: 0; top:0; bottom:0;
    background-color: blue;
}
div{
   position: absolute;
   border-right:250px solid skyblue;
   border-top:250px solid skyblue;
   background-color: yellow;
   top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0;
}
header{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 250px;
    top: 0; left:0; right: 0;
    background-color:palegreen;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yLVuZ/2/)

Comment: Hi Mate, this is how the project should look like: http://postimg.org/image/no7gsn23z/
i'm having the issue separating the content to two columns instead of one. i need to create the side bar on the right hand side.

Comment: What I posted to you should do the work. The div is the wider and nav is the thinner column. What else do you need?